# Cat playing with mouse broke my Windows/Explorer :( Cannot click buttons in most of standard apps/menus

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, cat

My mouse was laying on a sofa (I was going to clean it a bit) and my cat suddenly decided to play with the mouse (while the start menu was opened). Nothing serious happened with it during these 10 seconds, just few icons moved and volume bar appeared. But after that I found that Windows/Explorer does not work properly anymore. *(could be totaly unrelated to the mouse and cat of course)*

I cannot click icons in start menu (nothing happens) as well as buttons in some applications like Edge (back, refresh), update checker or any other new settings windows (personalize, etc.), buttons in the applications context menu on the taskbar, buttons in the CTRL+ALT+DEL screen.

With keyboard it works fine. In other applications mouse works, so I think it is fine. Also tried different mouse (and different USB ports), the same problem.

Restart and killing/restarting explorer.exe process did not help. `sfc /scannow` and `DISM` did not find anything.

Win 10 x64 Pro 10240

**UPD**:
I tried to create new user account, looks like it works fine in new local account.

But moving to new account does not look like convenient workaround since I would probably need to set a lot of things again, reinstall some applications, etc. :( Also I am not even sure how to do this with non-local accounts because I can't add two users with the same MS account.

Would be better to solve it without moving to new account.

Comment: Does the mouse work on the original account if you boot into safe mode?

Comment: Also great usage of the [tag:cat] tag :D

Comment: @Burgi yes, it works in safe mode. And after I booted back into normal mode it works fine so far. 0_o Thank you :)

Comment: The only thing my research showed that could cause this was turning on active desktop. I would recommend withholding noms until the cat tells you what it did...